# SimpleMembership confusion: InitializeDatabaseFile is not a member of WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity

Tags: asp.net, simplemembership

Has this method been deprecated? Can't find any info in any docs.

This is where I originally found the code:

http://blog.osbornm.com/2010/07/21/using-simplemembership-with-asp.net-webpages/

http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx

```
//Set up Simple Membership
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseFile(“SecurityDemo.sdf”, “Users”, “UserID”, “Username”, true);
```

Looks to me it has been replaced with this method?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg569134(v=vs.111).aspx

Are these the exact same methods with just a name change?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, InitializeDatabaseFile has been depreciated for InitializeDatabaseConnection. The main difference is that depreciated method took the database name (in this example an MS SQL Server Compact Edition database), whereas the new method takes the name of the connection string for your database that is defined in the web.config. And it is not limited to the Compact Edition. You can learn more about initializing SimpleMembership in this [article on customizing and seeding SimpleMembership](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2013/01/seeding-customizing-aspnet-mvc.html).

Comment: Nice article. Do you know why and when it was deprecated? Are there any docs or links with more info?

Comment: Not sure when it was depreciated. The article you reference on it is about 3 years old now. If I were to speculate why it was depreciated it is because defining a database connection with a connection string is much more powerful. I am not sure what specific documentation you are looking for. If you just want the spec on WebSecurity you can find it here. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.websecurity(v=vs.111).aspx